# How do I replace a background image on a panel in code? C#

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, background, panel

In the app I'm building in Unity3d, I want to be able to have the user choose a background image for the main panel. At the moment, I'm getting null when I debug out the variables. If someone could point me in the right direction.

```
public Image Background;
public Sprite theImage;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    theImage = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/sf1");
    Debug.Log(theImage);
    Background.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=theImage;
    Debug.Log(theImage);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One thing to remember is that there is no such thing as a panel. "But I just created one" I hear you say. Sure, Unity makes you think you did. But if you look at the gameobject it created, you'll see it's nothing more than a GameObject with a RectTransform component and and Image component.

So if you were to add your own component to this Panel, all you'd need to do is something along the lines of

```
Image image = GetComponent<Image>();
image.sprite = mySprite;
```

So your code is almost there, if not for the unassigned `Background`image.